# Set different Attributes for Dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How can I set Attributes to dynamically added buttons? I've tried but if I change `attr` all button types also bind together. I want to set `{type:Submit}` to first added button, `{type:Reset}` to second button, and `{type:Cancel}` to third button. How can I set different `attr` values to 3 different buttons?

[Working DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ESUgvVGLo4hsPwdpbPTg?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('AddCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {

  $scope.add_Button = function(index) {
        var buttonhtml = '<div ng-click="selectButton()"><button id="button_Type">Button</button>//click//</div>';
        var button = $compile(buttonhtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('add')).append(button);
        
            $scope.changeTosubmit = function () {
            var els = document.body.querySelectorAll('#button_Type');
            for (var i = 0, ils = els.length; i < ils; i++) {
                var el = els[i];
                el.setAttribute("type", "submit");
                compile(el);
            }
        };
        $scope.changeToreset = function () {
            var els = document.body.querySelectorAll('#button_Type');
            for (var i = 0, ils = els.length; i < ils; i++) {
                var el = els[i];
                el.setAttribute("type", "reset");
                compile(el);
            }
        };
        $scope.changeTocancel = function () {
            var els = document.body.querySelectorAll('#button_Type');
            for (var i = 0, ils = els.length; i < ils; i++) {
                var el = els[i];
                el.setAttribute("type", "cancel");
                compile(el);
            }
        };
};

    $scope.selectButton = function () {
$scope.showButton_Types = true;
    };
  
});
function compile(element) {
    var el = angular.element(element);
    $scope = el.scope();
    $injector = el.injector();
    $injector.invoke(function ($compile) {
        $compile(el)($scope);
    });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
    <button ng-click="add_Button($index)">Add Buttons</button>
<hr>
 <div id="add"></div>
 <form ng-show="showButton_Types">
      <div>            
        <label>change button types(?)</label><br/>
        <input ng-click="changeTosubmit()" name="submit" type="radio">&nbsp;Submit
        <input ng-click="changeToreset()" name="submit" type="radio">&nbsp;Reset
        <input ng-click="changeTocancel()" name="submit" type="radio">&nbsp;Cancel
      </div>
 </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did quite  research on this and here is the solution I came up with. I think this would be useful and perfectly match into your case. Instead if else you should have try AngularJs directives as below. For references visit

https://github.com/yearofmoo/angular-forms-refactor

and to understand how directive and its scope works here is perfect explanation with example visit

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

```js
angular.module('FieldEditor', [])

.controller("FieldEditorPageController",
    function() {

      var self = this;
      this.fields = [{
        type: 'submit'
      }];

      this.inputTypes = [{
        value: "reset",
        title: "button[reset]"
      }, {
        value: "cancel",
        title: "button[cancel]"
      }, {
        value: "submit",
        title: "button[submit]"
      }];

      this.newField = function() {
        self.fields.push({
          type: 'submit'
        });
      };

      this.removeField = function(field) {
        var index = self.fields.indexOf(field);
        if (index >= 0) {
          self.fields.splice(index, 1);
        }
      };
    })
  .controller("appButtonController", ['$scope', '$attrs',
    function($scope, $attrs) {
      var self = this;
      var directiveScope = $scope.$parent;
      this.options = directiveScope.$eval($attrs.model);
      this.onOk = function() {
        alert(self.options.type + ' button clicked');
      }
    }
  ])
  .directive('appButton', function($compile) {
    return {
      transclude: true,
      template: '<button ng-click="buttonCtrl.onOk()" type="">{{type|uppercase}}</button>',
      scope: {
        title: '@',
        type: '@'
      },
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      controller: 'appButtonController',
      controllerAs: 'buttonCtrl',
    }
  })

angular.module("MyApp", ['FieldEditor']);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <title>
    Dynamic Fields and Directive Binding
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="MyApp">
    <h1>Dynamic Fields and Directive Binding</h1>
    <div ng-controller="FieldEditorPageController as pageCtrl">

      <div>
        <div ng-repeat="field in pageCtrl.fields track by $index">
          <div>
            <div>
              {{ $index + 1 }}.
            </div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <label>Button Type:</label>
                <select ng-model="field.type" ng-options="entry.value as entry.title for entry in pageCtrl.inputTypes" name="field_type" required>
                </select>
                <app-button type="{{field.type}}" text="button" model="field">
                </app-button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <a href="" ng-click="pageCtrl.removeField(field)">Remove</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
                        <a href="" ng-click="pageCtrl.newField()">
                        Add Button
                        </a>
                    </span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice to learn, it helped you @VijjuSena. Directives scopes, compiler and its linking is quite challenging but once mastered, real power of AngularJs can be uncovered. This exercise helped me as well, thanks and welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is that you are creating elements that all have the same id.

From MDN:

> The Element.id property represents the element's identifier, reflecting the id global attribute.
>
> **It must be unique** in a document, and is often used to retrieve the element using `getElementById`. Other common usages of id include using the element's ID as a selector when styling the document with CSS.

-- [Mozilla Developer Network -- Web API -- Element.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)

So in your code create html with **unique** id attributes.

```
var buttonId = 0;
function buttonhtml() {
    buttonId++;
    return '<div ng-click="selectButton(' +buttonId+ ')">' +
           '<button id="button-' +buttonId+ '">' +
           'Button #' +buttonId+ 
           '</button></div>';
};
var button = $compile(buttonhtml())($scope);
```

By doing this you will be creating conformant HTML and you will be able to change specific button attributes using `getElementById`.